# SQL Server 2008 query for members who meet multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I searched for this and found similar queries, but none that gave the specific results I am seeking.

I have a table of all phone numbers called. I need a list of ALL `OrigNumber` who dialed EACH of three different `TermNumber`.

I tried:

```
SELECT OrigNumber FROM tbl_DetailCalls
WHERE (TermNumber='2463332121' AND TermNumber='2463334920' AND TermNumber='2463339901')
GROUP BY OrigNumber
```

I only need one instance of each `OrigNumber` that meets the condition.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you **show us** the table definitions (columns, datatypes) and sample data, and the required output from that sample data???

Comment: OrigNumber CHAR  TermNumber=TermAreaExchange INT + TermNumber CHAR  <br/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select orignumber
From tbl_DetailCalls
Where termnumber in ('2463332121', '2463334920', '2463339901')
Group by orignumber
Having count(distinct termnumber)>=3
```

Sorry for format. Sent from phone.

Comment: Thanks, that works, or at least gives a result. But I'm not sure how that guarantees that ALL conditions were met (that that OrigNumber called EACH of the three TermNumber).

Comment: @user1024050: `Where termnumber in ('2463332121', '2463334920', '2463339901')` only selects those items that match *at least one* of the three given `termnumber` values. `Having count(distinct termnumber)>=3`, which evaluates after `group by`, filters the results further, leaving only those `orignumber`s that have at least 3 distinct associated `termnumber`s (which are in fact those specified in the `WHERE` clause). It should probably be just `count(distinct termnumber)=3`, not `...>=3`, because the count can never exceed 3 in this case.

Comment: @user1024050: So, in short, the idea is to select items that match the specified values, then, as the next step, leave only those that match all of them. (We have specified 3 items, so the count to check should be 3 as well.)

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for the explanation (and edits); I'm finally back at a real keyboard.  Your explanation was perfect.  As an aside, I used >= in case the business rule ever changed to "calls made to 3 of [x] numbers"

Comment: Thanks again. But, just to be absolutely clear, would it not count to three if there were three calls to the second number only, for example?

Comment: Nope; that's what the DISTINCT term does in the COUNT; it only COUNT's unique termnumbers for each Orignumber

Comment: I listed out the call records and hand counted (just to be sure) and absolutely confirmed that it worked. I appreciated y'alls assistance. I will payback when the opportunity arises.